# Wootrade V3 API authentication in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have taken the example code from https://docs.woo.org/?shell#authentication and have adapted the code to get the V3 normalised request to use in the signature generation. For endpoints that don't require any parameters, this works fine, but if parameters are required, I get this error:

> "{'success': False, 'code': -1001, 'message': 'The API signature is invalid.'}"

I have checked my API key and secret and the settings on my account, and everything should be fine.

```py
import datetime
import hmac, hashlib, base64
import requests
import json


staging_api_secret_key = 'MY API SECRET'
staging_api_key = 'MY API KEY'

def _generate_signature(data):
  key = staging_api_secret_key#'key' # Defined as a simple string.
  key_bytes= bytes(key , 'utf-8') # Commonly 'latin-1' or 'utf-8'
  data_bytes = bytes(data, 'utf-8') # Assumes `data` is also a string.
  return hmac.new(key_bytes, data_bytes , hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


milliseconds_since_epoch = round(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)

headers = {
    'x-api-timestamp': str(milliseconds_since_epoch),
    'x-api-key': staging_api_key,
    'x-api-signature': _generate_signature(str(milliseconds_since_epoch)+'POST/v3/algo/order{ "symbol": "SPOT_BTC_USDT",  "side": "BUY",  "reduceOnly": false,  "type": "MARKET",  "quantity": "0.0001",  "algoType": "TRAILING_STOP",  "callbackRate": "0.012"}'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control':'no-cache'
}
data = {"symbol": "SPOT_BTC_USDT",  "side": "BUY",  "reduceOnly": False,  "type": "MARKET",  "quantity": "0.0001",  "algoType": "TRAILING_STOP",  "callbackRate": "0.012"}



response = requests.post('https://api.woo.org/v3/algo/order', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: It is supposed to be a `POST` request. `GET` requests do not support a body.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thanks! I have changed it to post, but then I get that the API signature is incorrect although I checked and the key and secret are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Customer support came with the following code that seems to work:

```
import datetime
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import hmac
import requests
import json
 
API_SECRET = ""
API_KEY = ""
API_ENDPOINT_BASE = ""
 
ts = round(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
algo_order ={}
algo_order["symbol"] = "SPOT_BTC_USDT"
algo_order["side"] = "BUY"
algo_order["type"] = "MARKET"
algo_order["quantity"] = "1"
algo_order["algoType"] = "STOP"
algo_order["triggerPrice"] = "27500"
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(algo_order, indent=4)
#hashed_sig = hashlib.sha256(API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'))
def _generate_signature(data):
  key = API_SECRET#'key' # Defined as a simple string.
  key_bytes= bytes(key , 'utf-8') # Commonly 'latin-1' or 'utf-8'
  data_bytes = bytes(data, 'utf-8') # Assumes `data` is also a string.
  return hmac.new(key_bytes, data_bytes , hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
 
sign = str(ts) + "POST/v3/algo/order"+json_formatted_str
api_endpoint = API_ENDPOINT_BASE + "v3/algo/order"
userdata = requests.post(api_endpoint,
                       headers={
                           "x-api-signature": _generate_signature(sign),
                           "x-api-timestamp": str(ts),
                           "x-api-key": API_KEY,
                           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       },data=json_formatted_str
)
print(userdata.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(algo_order, indent=4)

......

sign = str(ts) + "POST/v3/algo/order"+json_formatted_str

......

userdata = requests.post(api_endpoint,
                       headers={
                           "x-api-signature": _generate_signature(sign),
                           "x-api-timestamp": str(ts),
                           "x-api-key": API_KEY,
                           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       },data=json_formatted_str
)
```

These part is the point and finally worked